# JIRA Updates to slack DMs

Tags: jira, webhooks, slack

We use Slack and JIRA, and the Slack connector to push JIRA updates into a #jira-updates Slack channel.

I'm wondering if anyone knows if the connector (or another tool) can post updates to Slack as a direct message to the watcher list for an issue? It owuld be really good if my DM feed had updates from JIRA which were applicable to me, rather than having to trawl the whole channel looking for my name.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like a spam risk to me!

Comment: Hmm, not sure I agree, the more spammy approach to me seems like having one channel full of things which aren't necessarily relevant to you, but having to trawl them anyway just in case.